# transferring colors from Paletton to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I started to work  with Paletton.com. I need to get  color scheme to Adobe Illustrator.  I see .aso among output (export) formats in Paletton and  I understand that I can load  this .aso in Photoshop, then export those swatches in .ase  (exchange) format and finally  open this .ase in Illustrator. This method works but I am wondering if there is a better and quicker workflow to get colors from Paletton to Illustrator.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you directly with paletton, but I made a tool for creating and exporting color palettes to ASE format, amongst other stuff.. ([sidesketch.com](https://sidesketch.com)). It's a little rough around the edges still, but it might help you out.

For example, here's some of the material UI colours - https://sidesketch.com/palette/73 - hit 'adobe swatch' and you can import the created ASE file directly into AI.

Comment: Thank you, danp. But for now I will continue using very impressive  Paletton.com    As I said I know the way of transferring the colors to AI, just looking for how to streamline the workflow.  Meanwhile I found some improvement - to export .png from paletton and to open it directly in Illustrator. After that some work with color picker in AI  pretty much does the job.  I appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: that seems like a reasonable workaround. you could try using something like sip (if on a mac) too.